# search query in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, full-text-search, querydsl

I have documents like the below in my elasticsearch

```
{"method":"POST","url":"/saas/services/1.0/account/*/purchase/*/subscription/cancel"}
{"method":"POST","url":"/saas/services/1.0/account/*/purchase/*/cancel"}
```

I am searching these documents using node.js client. Below is the query I am sending.

Example 1 type : DSL

```
client.search({
    index: 'my_node',
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: {
                    match: { method: 'POST' },
                    match: { url: '/saas/services/1.0/account/*/purchase/*/cancel' }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output
I am getting the other record with subscription cancel. The query is not matching the exact document. I tried the below query , it worked for this case but not working for few other test cases.

document

```
  {"method":"POST","url":"/paas/service/1.0/act/*/purchase"}}
    {"method":"GET","url":"/paas/service/1.0/act/*/purchase"}}
    {"method":"PUT","url":"/paas/service/1.0/act/*/purchase"}}
```

Example 2 type : query string

```
    client.search({
  index: 'my_node',
  q: 'method: POST AND url: /saas/services/1.0/account/*/purchase'
}
```

Output

I get the GET purchase document regardless of other two. Tried for few other documents, the method argument is not getting recognized.

How do I write elasticsearch query to search through the documents to match both the properties of method and url. i had tried query time boosting for the url but doesn't seem to work.

Edit - Mapping information

```
 {
  "nodeclient": {
    "mappings": {
      "logs": {
        "properties": {
          "method": {
            "type": "string" },
          "url": {
            "type": "string" }
     } } }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of your documents? Can you update your question with the output you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_node/_mapping`

Comment: @val I have updated the post with Mapping information. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try add quotation marks

> client.search({ index: 'my_node', body: { "query": { "bool": { "must": {
>   "match": { "method": 'POST' }, "match": { "url":
>   '/saas/services/1.0/account/*/purchase/*/cancel' } } } } } }

Answer (score 0):

I tried optimizing the query with [Mirage plugin](https://github.com/appbaseio/mirage/blob/dev/README.md) for elasticsearch queries. I was trying with different examples and saw the responses. Below is my final query that works for my scenario

```
          {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        { "match_phrase": { "url": uri }},
                        { "match": { "method": http } }
                    ]}
            }
```

match_phrase suited better for the url parameter. Also I missed the array part inside the must clause.